# Chrome browser crashing with many tabs open

Tags: chrome-for-android, samsung-galaxy-s-6, browser-tabs

I use a Samsung Galaxy S6 `Edge`  but there was no tag for the "edge" version and I don't have the rep to create it.

I have had between 300-500 tabs open in the Chrome browser for quite a while, and I noticed some behaviors that I'm curious about.

Chrome crashes a lot when switching tabs or closing tabs. In particular:

a) There seems to be no limit on how many new tabs I can open, but it gets slow when the number of tabs is high

b) When closing tabs, I can always close 2 tabs but if I close 3, chrome will crash. 
To prevent this from happening, I have to close 2 tabs, then switch one remaining tab into focus and let it load for a few seconds, then go back to the tab overview, close 2 more, switch one into focus, and so on. It always crashes if I close 3 tabs, which makes me wonder if there is a bug in the code for restructuring the tab list/stack/whatever holds them.

c) When switching tabs, I need to be careful not to scroll too far. Meaning it usually works to switch to the nearest +/- 1  or  2 tabs away from the current one. But Chrome will often crash if I scroll further away than that.

At some point, I made the effort to count all the tabs and ended up around 400. That was without switching any tab into focus, so it seems that scrolling far is ok without crashing, as long as I don't switch a far away tab in focus.

d) When it crashes during tab switching, it "forgets" that I had closed some tabs and on the next restart, those tabs are back again. It seems that the tab list/stack is written into storage whenever bringing a tab into focus, why the method in b) of closing max 2 at a time is the only way to reduce the number of tabs. Step by step, but time consuming.

Is this device specific? Does anyone have insights into why it works like this?